# Can not use proxyForObject function in DelegateProxyType (rxSwift)

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I try to migrate delegate of SRWebSocket to observable. This is my RxSocketManagerDelegateProxy.swift:

```
class RxSocketManagerDelegateProxy: DelegateProxy, DelegateProxyType{

static func currentDelegateFor(object: AnyObject) -> AnyObject?{
    let socket: SRWebSocket = object as! SRWebSocket
    return socket.delegate
}

static func setCurrentDelegate(delegate: AnyObject?, toObject object: AnyObject) {
    let socket: SRWebSocket = object as! SRWebSocket
    socket.delegate = delegate as? SRWebSocketDelegate
}

}

extension SRWebSocket{
    public var rx_delegate: DelegateProxy{
    return DelegateProxyType.proxyForObject(self)
}

// ...

}
```

The problem is in proxyForObject function. It is not compiled like above. I get warning "Static member 'proxyForObject' cannot be used on instance of type 'DelegateProxyType.Protocol'".

When I try to use proxyForObjectFunction like this (though it is deprecated):

```
public var rx_delegate: DelegateProxy{
    return proxyForObject(RxSocketManagerDelegateProxy.self, self)
}
```

I get message "assertion failed: : file /Users/Agentum/Documents/Xcode/Telemetry/Pods/RxCocoa/RxCocoa/Common/DelegateProxyType.swift".

How should I use proxyForObject() function in order to migrate the delegate correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be calling `proxyForObject` on `RxSocketManagerDelegateProxy`, not `DelegateProxyType`.

```
extension SRWebSocket {
    public var rx_delegate: DelegateProxy {
        return RxSocketManagerDelegateProxy.proxyForObject(self)
        // instead of: `return DelegateProxyType.proxyForObject(self)`
    }
}
```