# How to properly convert a 3rd party library delegate into a RxSwift Observable

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a case where I am using a 3rd party library and I would like to make it into an Observable. Appropriately, the library is designed around delegates as one would expect so I am wrapping it.  The library performs an async operation and calls it's delegate with the results when it completes.

I definitely want to take advantage of the `cold` nature of the observable and only start the operation when someone subscribes. I have a solution that works, I just don't know if it's deeply flawed and I am missing some important understanding of `RxSwift` or perhaps there is a simpler way to achieve the same goal.

```
public final class RxLibBridge: LibDelegate{

    let lib = Lib()
    let _source = PublishSubject<[LibResult]>()

    public init(){
        lib.delegate = self
    }

    public func asObservable() -> Observable<[LibResult]>{
        // create a cold observable to start
        // the Lib's async operation on subscribe.
        return Observable<Void>.create{
            observer in

            self.lib.startOperation()

            // emit and complete
            observer.onNext(())
            observer.onCompleted()
            return Disposables.create()
        }
        // convert the `Void` observable into an observable from the 
        // PublishSubject
        .flatMapLatest{self._source}
    }

    // the lib's completion delegate method
    public func lib(_ lib: Lib, didFinishWithResult results: [LibResult]) {
        // grab the PublishSubject, emit the result and complete
        let observer = _source.asObserver()
        observer.onNext(results)
        observer.onCompleted()
    }
}
```

So my question is: Is this an appropriate pattern in Rx? Again, it works:

```
RxLibBridge()
    .asObservable()
    .subscribe(...)
```

Just because it works though doesn't mean I have not fundamentally misunderstood the proper way to work with this situation.

I know there is a way in RxSwift to handle something like this:

https://medium.com/@maxofeden/rxswift-migrate-delegates-to-beautiful-observables-3e606a863048#.rksg2ckpj

https://samritchie.net/2016/05/12/rxswift-delegateproxy-with-required-methods/

I tried this approach but it looks like the API changed since 2015. Namely, in the example links above `proxyForObject` cannot be found when adding the `rx_delegate` method in the extension.

Additionally, this approach appears to favor pure `Objective-C` [UIKit/AppKit] APIs. In my attempt to follow the linked example, I was editing the source of the 3rd party lib to make the delegate method `optional` and exposing it to `@objc`. The lib's delegate is `required` and I would rather not have to fork the lib to make the modifications.

This SO answer provided the updated API for the 2 links above:

[Can not use proxyForObject function in DelegateProxyType (rxSwift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325626/can-not-use-proxyforobject-function-in-delegateproxytype-rxswift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after digging some more, it looks like this will do the trick with a required delegate method, updated for `RxSwift 3.3.1`. This is using their `DelegateProxy` system.

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import Lib


public final class RxLibDelegate: DelegateProxy, LibDelegate, DelegateProxyType{

    let _subject = PublishSubject<[LibResult]>()

    public static func currentDelegateFor(_ object: AnyObject) -> AnyObject?{
        let target = object as! Lib
        return target.delegate
    }

    public static func setCurrentDelegate(_ delegate: AnyObject?, toObject object: AnyObject) {
        let target = object as! Lib
        target.delegate = delegate as? LibDelegate
    }

    public func lib(_ lib: Lib, didFinishWithResult results: [LibResult]) {
        _subject.onNext(results)
        _subject.onCompleted()
    }
}



extension Lib{

    public var rx_delegate: DelegateProxy{
        // `proxyForDelegate` moved as compared to examples at:
        // https://samritchie.net/2016/05/12/rxswift-delegateproxy-with-required-methods/
        // https://medium.com/@maxofeden/rxswift-migrate-delegates-to-beautiful-observables-3e606a863048#.rksg2ckpj

        return RxLibDelegate.proxyForObject(self)
    }

    public var rx_libResults: Observable<[LibResult]> {
        // `proxyForDelegate` moved as compared to examples at:
        // https://samritchie.net/2016/05/12/rxswift-delegateproxy-with-required-methods/
        // https://medium.com/@maxofeden/rxswift-migrate-delegates-to-beautiful-observables-3e606a863048#.rksg2ckpj

        let proxy = RxLibDelegate.proxyForObject(self)
        return proxy._subject
    }
}
```

That's about 28 LOC. My original "wrapper" (see updated version below) but I don't know if it's the best is 21 LOC; 6 of 1 half dozen of the other?

In my particular case I only have 1 delegate method to worry about. If you were working with some functionality that had multiple delegates I think the `DelegateProxy` + `extension` methods would be a lot more practical and the better choice in that case.

Regarding my original trial wrapping thing using that `Void` observable, it appears it's totally acceptable to alter the stream with `flatMapLatest` as evidenced here re: Sending continual events while a button is pressed:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39123102/1060314

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa


let button = submitButton.rx_controlEvent([.TouchDown])
button
.flatMapLatest { _ in
    Observable<Int64>.interval(0.1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .takeUntil(self.submitButton.rx_controlEvent([.TouchUpInside]))
}
.subscribeNext{ x in print("BOOM \(x)") }
.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

//prints BOOM 0 BOOM 1 BOOM 2 BOOM 3 BOOM 4 BOOM 5 for every 0.1 seconds
```

Note that a new `Observable` is returned from `flatMapLatest`. The author cites the `RxSwift slack channel`, so I assume it is at least acceptable to do.

Here's an updated version of my wrapper version that I think might be a bit cleaner:

```
import RxSwift


public final class RxLibBridge: LibDelegate{

    let lib = Lib()
    let _source = PublishSubject<[LibResult]>()

    public init(){
        lib.delegate = self
    }

    public func asObservable() -> Observable<[LibResult]>{
        // create a cold observable to start
        // the Lib's async operation on subscribe.
        return Observable.just(())
            .do(onNext: {
                self.lib.startOperation()
            })
            .flatMapLatest{self._source}
    }

    // the lib's completion delegate method
    public func lib(_ lib: Lib, didFinishWithResult results: [LibResult]) {
        // grab the PublishSubject, emit the result and complete
        _source.onNext(results)
        _source.onCompleted()
    }
}
```